# How to get Inserted Table ID Column using stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, stored-procedures

As i previously asked the question but in vein to get out of the issue,  actually i'm inserting a table with 3 records and i want to get the ID of those 3 records that have been inserted in this session of Stored Procedure. ProdID is PK and Auto Increment.
Example

```
ProdID  Name    Batch   Qty     ExpDate
2       ABC      S4      3      2018-6-31
3       DEF      D3      5      2018-6-31
4       GHI      U15     7      2018-6-31
```

and I want to get all the 3 inserted record ID (ProdID) from output.
Kindly do me a favor i'm suffering this for couple of days.
Thanks

Comment: Sql server? Oracle? MySQL?

Comment: I've just updated my answer to your previous question. If you still can't get it to work on your system, Please try to edit the original question instead of posting another one. I'm Closing this one as a duplicate.